# C multithread shared variable

Tags: c, multithreading

I need help with multithreading in C.

Initially, I have a variable named `client` in the `main` function.

```
void *my_function (void *arg) {
    int *client = (int*)arg;
    *client = 5;
    return 0;
}

void *my_function2 (void *arg) { ... }
void *my_function3 (void *arg) { ... }


int main()
{
    int client = 0;
    pthread_t connect_thread, func2_thread, func3_thread;
    pthread_create(&connect_thread, NULL, my_function, (void *)&client);
    pthread_create(&func2_thread, NULL, my_function2, (void *)&client);
    pthread_create(&func3_thread, NULL, my_function3, (void *)&client);

    // how can i make it such that after executing my_function, client's value = 5 in main()??

    pthread_join(my_function, NULL);

    // once the value is updated, i will pass this updated value into another thread

    pthread_join(my_function2, NULL);
    pthread_join(my_function3, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I change the value of `client` in `main` from 0 to 5 after the execution of `my_function`?

Comment: How do you know it's not already 5?

Comment: I have deleted my answer. The original question was solved, and I am asked to be a code-writing-service. That's what new questions are for.

Comment: @Dogbert I'm sorry if i offended you in any way. In no way am I asking anyone to write a code because I'm lazy or what. I am already reading articles for the past 2 hours and couldn't solve my problem which is why i posted here. I'm still very new to C programming and multithreading. Sorry if i offended you.

Comment: C Primer Plus by Steve Prata, and the following link will give you a very good start with threads programming in C. https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: @Dogbert I appreciate the assistance you have provided in your answer. I will continue to look further into that.

Comment: I'll leave the answer up, since others might benefit from it too. In the future, if you need the answer extended, please create a new question. A very common response to these questions is "SO is not a code writing service". The answer provided should serve as a good springboard to your final solution. Here's an example for spawning multiple threads too: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Joining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when `main()` completes, it terminates the entire program, all other threads included. Your code will indeed modify the value of `client`, but it isn't doing it in a safe way (in general), as you should be using mutexes to protect data accessed in multiple threads. It's most likely your program is terminating before the thread is fully created.

You need to add mutexes to your code, and use `pthread_join()` to wait for the thread to complete before allowing `main()` to complete and `return`. Please refer to the corrected example below.

---

## Code Listing

---

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Preprocessor directives
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>


/*******************************************************************************
 * Globals
 ******************************************************************************/
pthread_mutex_t mDataMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

/*******************************************************************************
 * Function prototypes
 ******************************************************************************/
void *my_function(void *arg);


/*******************************************************************************
 * Function definitions
 ******************************************************************************/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void *my_function(void *arg)
{
    int *client = (int*)arg;
    printf("Thread started.\n");

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mDataMutex);
    *client = 5;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mDataMutex);

    printf("Thread completed.\n");

    return 0;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main(void)
{
    int client = 0;
    int rc;
    void *status;
    pthread_t connect_thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    // Print initial value of variable.
    printf("Initial value of client:%d.\n", client);

    /* Initialize and set thread detached attribute */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    // Create the thread and start it.
    rc = pthread_create(&connect_thread, &attr, my_function, (void *)&client);
    if (rc)
    {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        return (-1);
    }

    // Clean  up the attribute struct, don't need it anymore
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    // Wait for the thread to complete.
    rc = pthread_join(connect_thread, &status);

    // Print update value of client
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mDataMutex);
    printf("Updated value of client:%d.\n", client);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mDataMutex);

    return 0;
}
```

---

## Sample Output

---

```
Initial value of client:0.
Thread started.
Thread completed.
Updated value of client:5.
```

---

Comment: I don't think you need a mutex here - `pthread_join` should suffice. (If you weren't waiting for the thread to finish, then you'd use a mutex)

Comment: @Dogbert I'm not sure why do you use pthread_join twice.. The examples from the website only joined it once. Confused about this part.

Comment: @immibis That is correct in this case, but if OP is new to threads, I want to encourage good habits (and bring attention to the existence of mutexes) as soon as possible, even if it is overkill in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already changes the value. The **error in your code** is in the `pthread_join` call which takes as input a thread id of type `pthread_t` (`connect_thread` variable in your case) while you passed to it the function.

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void *my_function (void *arg) {
    int *client = (int*)arg;
    *client = 5;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int client = 0;
    pthread_t connect_thread, func2_thread, func3_thread;
    pthread_create(&connect_thread, NULL, my_function, (void *)&client);

    // how can i make it such that after executing my_function, client's value = 5 in main()??

    pthread_join(connect_thread, NULL);

    // once the value is updated, i will pass this updated value into another thread
    printf("%d\n", client);
    return 0;
}
```

Another alternative is to use a global variable and mutex to change the value.